# Firebase dynamic link and android Navigation architecture component

Tags: android, firebase, android-architecture-components, firebase-dynamic-links

How to integrate firebase dynamic link with new android navigation architecture component. My app have one activity and many fragments. Please help with recommended way.

Answer (score 0):

First, [create an implicit deep link](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link#implicit) and make sure that it works before moving on.

Finally, create a Dynamic Link in the [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/) by following the step-by-step form :

[image]

Comment: Is this working also for Long Dynamic Link? When I click long dynamic link, it does nothing

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57868086/navigation-component-seems-just-working-with-short-dynamic-link-firebase?noredirect=1#comment102471419_57868086