# Navigation component seems to work only with short dynamic link (firebase)

Tags: android, firebase, androidx, firebase-dynamic-links

Example:
Long Dynamic Link

```
https://domaindebug.page.link/?link=https://www.website.com&apn=com.x.debug&isi=122...6&ibi=com.ios.x.debug&efr=1
```

Short Dynamic Link

```
https://domaindebug.page.link/register
```

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_register"
        android:name="com.x.presentation.feature.identification.view.RegisterFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_register">
        <action
            ... />
        <argument
            android:name="code"
            android:defaultValue="@null"
            app:argType="string"
            app:nullable="true" />
        <deepLink
            android:id="@+id/deepLink"
            app:uri="https://domaindebug.page.link/register?code={code}" />
</fragment>
```

If I click on long dynamic link, nothing happens.
How can I manage this? I also can't find any documentation about integrating firebase dynamic deeplink + navigation component

Comment: how are you setting it for short url?

Comment: as in the example

Comment: your host of long url is different than 'domaindebug.page.link'? right?

Comment: this is my long url https://domaindebug.page.link/?link=https://www.website.com&apn=com.x.debug&isi=122...6&ibi=com.ios.x.debug&efr=1

Comment: are you sure?because that .page.link gets appended in firebase short url only.

Comment: https://domaindebug.page.link is just a hostname as any other.

Comment: How do you register your long deep link in the navigation graph?

Comment: if host of short and long urls are different, which most of the times are, then you can add deeplink attribute for both of them. can you keep host of your long url other than .page.link?

Comment: Traditional way, because I have a deeplink by environment @esentsov

Comment: how do you know your long url's not working, if both host name are same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have not seen any official integration of dynamic links with the navigation component so far. But it's pretty simple to integrate them manually by fetching the link with help of `FirebaseDynamicLinks` and passing it to the `NavController`:

```
FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance()
            .getDynamicLink(intent)
            .addOnSuccessListener(this) { link ->
                findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment).handleDeepLink(Intent().apply {
                    data = link?.link
                })
            }
```

Please check out the [sample project](https://github.com/esentsov/dynamic-links-sample) I've created to show the idea. It handles deep links in a separate activity to make UI smoother, but hands over the link to the navigation component for handling.

Comment: But why should I declare the long deeplink with navigation components? Without navigation components , I can declare the short link in each activity (Android manifest) and deal it with getDynamicLink

Comment: @rguerra So you want to fetch `https://www.website.com` part from the link and pass it to the navigation library, right?

Comment: yes @esentsov, but in navigation components I just have a single activity. Should this activity manage all the deeplinks (FirebaseDynamicLinks) and redirect the user to each fragment?

Comment: @rguerra yes, with the above approach the activity fetches all the deeplinks from `FirebaseDynamicLinks` and passes them to the navigation component to process. That's how navigation library handles the links itself - catches them in the main activity and processes.

Comment: But it "passes them to the navigation component" automatically? Or do I need to have a switch/when case for each fragment? I don't see it very clean honestly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199778/discussion-between-esentsov-and-rguerra).

Comment: If you have created the implicit deep link following the documentation, you don't need to add this code. Adding this code will result in the handling of deep links twice.

Comment: Using this approach my backstack is gone. I am landing to the fragment but previous fragments are not maintained. Its not even going to the start destination app is just killed after back press @esentsov

Comment: @Dr.aNdRO [this link](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link#implicit) explains when the back stack is maintained and when it's not, might be helpful

Comment: @esentsov where to write the above code? inside mainActivity or destination fragment?