# Deep Link using Navigation Component not opening my destination fragment

Tags: android, deep-linking, android-navigation, android-navigation-graph

I'm using Android Navigation UI  for navigation in my app. I need to open a web URL (dynamic links) in my second fragment.

this is my code in the navigation graph

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/nav_home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:name="com.myproject.main.HomeFragment"
        android:label="Home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_home_to_secondFragment"
            app:destination="@id/secondFragment" />

    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_library"
        android:name="com.myproject.main.SecondFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_library"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_library">
       <deepLink
            android:id="@+id/deepLink"
            app:uri="https://myproject.page.link/*" />

    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

And added this navigation graph to my main activity in the manifest

```
<activity
     android:name=".main.MainActivity"
     android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
     android:label="@string/app_name"
     android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
      >
     <nav-graph android:value="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />
</activity>
```

I want to open my second fragment when the user clicks on a URL like `https://myproject.page.link/i5sA` but when I click on this link my app is even not prompted to open in this app. Only browsers are prompted. when I click on open with chrome browser it just opens my app with the default start destination.

what I need is when user press on that web URL I need to open my app MainActivity with SecondFragment and get that URL data instead of opening the default home fragment.

I had seen the [developer page](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link#implicit) and a lot of articles and tutorials but I don't know what I'm missing here, anyone can please tell me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `app:uri="https://myproject.page.link/*"`

Using `*` as a placeholder is not a valid deeplink in android architecture navigation.

Although the `https://myproject.page.link/*` URI is valid to open https://myproject.page.link/* exactly as-is (i.e. with the asterisk)

But [as per documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link#implicit):

> Path parameter placeholders in the form of {placeholder_name} match one or more characters. For example, [http://www.example.com/users/{id}](http://www.example.com/users/%7Bid%7D) matches http://www.example.com/users/4.

So, if you want to make this asterisk as a placeholder for some info to be passed to your app, you need to wrap this into curly braces {}; so your URI would be:

`app:uri="https://myproject.page.link/{placeholder_name}"`

Notice that you can test this URI from the Google search app (not the browser app), because if you want to open it from the browser you have to register the domain name globally; this is to allow Google verify that you are the owner of the URI. [Check here for more info](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations).

Comment: if I use `{data}` instead of `*` will my fragment handle that dynamic link with default `FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().getDynamicLink(getIntent())` ?

Comment: @Venkat .. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57868086/navigation-component-seems-just-working-with-short-dynamic-link-firebase) can help you out

Comment: In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57868086/navigation-component-seems-just-working-with-short-dynamic-link-firebase) he said handle deep link in another activity and after task successful open main activity. how to open main activity destination fragment with the data loaded in other link handler activity?

Comment: @Venkat Can you please open another question with relevant firebase tags so that someone can help you; also this goes beyond the scope in this question; but so far there is no other legitimate way to do that in navigation component other than mentioned in the answer.